# Calculations using 2 tables and reporting to a 3rd

Tags: mysql

So I've got 3 tables and I need to calculate a value from the first 2 and then update a field in the third table with that value, and I'm coming across an error.

```
UPDATE Characters AS c
SET c.Total_DKP = (
(SELECT c.Initial_DKP
FROM c
WHERE c.Name='harrian')-
(SELECT SUM(a.DKP_Change)
FROM Attendance AS a 
WHERE a.Name = 'harrian')
              )
WHERE c.Name = 'harrian' ;
```

it gives the error

```
Table 'harrian.c' doesn't exist
```

but when I run

```
UPDATE Characters AS c
SET c.Total_DKP = ( SELECT SUM(a.DKP_Change) 
                    FROM Attendance AS a 
                    WHERE a.Name = 'harrian'
                  )
WHERE c.Name = 'harrian'
```

I have no issues, can anyone tell me whats wrong with the first block?

Here is the full query-

```
UPDATE Characters AS c
SET c.Total_DKP = (
(SELECT c.Inital_DKP FROM Characters AS c WHERE c.Name = 'harrian')
+(SELECT SUM(a.DKP_Change) FROM Attendance AS a WHERE a.Name = 'harrian')
+(SELECT SUM(b.Cost) FROM Raid_Drops AS b WHERE b.Player_Name = 'harrian')
)
WHERE c.Name = 'harrian' ;
```

I'm now getting this error

```
You can't specify target table 'c' for update in FROM clause
```

Comment: Can there be more than one rows with `Name = 'harrian'` in table `Characters`?

Answer (score 1):

Your first subquery is:

```
SELECT c.Initial_DKP FROM c WHERE c.Name='harrian'
```

Instead of `FROM c` I think you mean `FROM Characters`:

```
SELECT Initial_DKP FROM Characters WHERE Name='harrian'
```

But if that is the case, the whole UPDATE is better written as

```
UPDATE Characters AS c
SET c.Total_DKP = c.Initial_DKP - (
  SELECT SUM(a.DKP_Change)
  FROM Attendance AS a 
  WHERE a.Name = 'harrian'
)
WHERE c.Name = 'harrian';
```

Because an update statement cannot use the table it's updating in a subquery.

Comment: Are you sure it's the *same* error, **Table 'harrian.c' doesn't exist**?

Comment: @Joni: THe Op probably has no `Initial_DKP ` column and all he wants is: `SET c.Total_DKP = c.Total_DKP - ...`

Comment: Or maybe he has 3 tables (but has shown us the names of only 2)

Comment: No, I had a syntax error when I changed it.  It gives a different error " You can't specify target table 'c' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: OP updated,  not sure what the issue is when I point back to the database I'm trying to update.

Comment: You can't use the table you are updating in a subquery of the update statement. Use the second form I posted, where initial_DKP is used without a sub select.

Answer (score 0):

If there can be no more than one row with `Name = 'harrian'` in table `Characters` (e.g if `Name` is `UNIQUE`), you can use:

```
UPDATE Characters AS c
SET c.Total_DKP = (
  c.Inital_DKP
  + (SELECT SUM(a.DKP_Change) FROM Attendance AS a WHERE a.Name = 'harrian')
  + (SELECT SUM(b.Cost) FROM Raid_Drops AS b WHERE b.Player_Name = 'harrian')
  )
WHERE c.Name = 'harrian' ;
```

Some parenthesis above are not needed. Also, to avoid the cases where `Attendance` or `Raid_Drops` have no rows with `Name = 'harrian'` and the `NULL` that will be produced by the `SUM()` over the empty tables, you need to convert the Nulls to zeros:

```
UPDATE Characters AS c
SET c.Total_DKP = 
  c.Inital_DKP
  + COALESCE( (SELECT SUM(a.DKP_Change) FROM Attendance AS a 
               WHERE a.Name = 'harrian')
            ), 0)
  + COALESCE( (SELECT SUM(b.Cost) FROM Raid_Drops AS b 
               WHERE b.Player_Name = 'harrian')
            ), 0)
WHERE c.Name = 'harrian' ;
```